# Manage Categories section in admin is missing expand plus signs beside parent categories in Magento 1.9

Tags: admin, category, category-tree

I have been working on developing a Magento site and today the little plus signs beside the categories on the `Manage Categories` section of the admin side disappeared.

I can still use `Expand All` to expand the category tree, but it is more difficult to navigate the categories this way.

*Any insight into why the plus signs would disappear?*

When the categories are expanded I still have the little minus sign to collapse them, but no plus signs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Troy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved this one on my own!

I just logged out, cleared my browser cache and logged back in to find the plus signs have returned. Maybe this will help someone else with the same issue.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I guess it was just your browser's cache.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that the question does not count as unanswered anymore